# Data type for coordinates that is part of sql record

Tags: sql, postgresql, coordinates, sqldatatypes

Thank you everyone for your help on this matter. I am working on inserting the following values to my table named lake: I am using postgresql on pgAdmin4.

```
INSERT INTO lake VALUES ('Inari',1040,92,119,NULL,'Paatsjoki',(68.95,27.7));
INSERT INTO lake VALUES ('Oulujaervi',928,35,123,NULL,'Oulujoki',(64.3,27.25));
INSERT INTO lake VALUES ('Kallavesi',472,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Vuoksi',(62.9,27.7));
INSERT INTO lake VALUES ('Saimaa',4370,85,76,NULL,'Vuoksi',(61.3,28.0));

    INSERT INTO public.lake
(
        name character varying(30), 
        area integer, 
        depth integer, 
        elevation integer,
        river character varying(30), 
        type character varying(30),
        coordinates integer
);
```

The column coordinate is an INT data type. However I am getting an error 
ERROR: column "coordinates" is of type int but expression is of type record.

Question: What datatype will enable the above data to store in my coordinate column without getting an error message?

Again, thank you all for your help.

Comment: Show structure of your table.

Comment: Just use the `ARRAY` type: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

Comment: Thank you for the feedback djthoms. I read the documentation and I am unable to declare coordinates as integers[][] through pgAdmin4 it only allows integer[]. Would there be a way through the command line perhaps to declare that specific column with the array types?

Comment: ERROR:  column "coordinates" is of type integer[] but expression is of type record

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`point` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html) here. Both coordinate values fit in a single `point` and there are [several functions that operate on points](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html), such as distance calculation and containment in other geometric objects. Note that it is customary to store point ordinates in (x,y) or (longitude,latitude) order.

If you need more complex operations on your coordinates, you could install the [`postgis` extension](http://www.postgis.org).